# Partially masking an email address

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi all I am having a little difficulty masking email addresses using SQL Developer (Oracle).

What I want to do is substitute all characters before the @ symbol in an email address except for the first and the last digit. For instance if my email address is:

myemail@gmail.com

then I would like the output to display m*****l@gmail.com

So far I have been using the replace, substr and instr functions and can get the right part to work but I do not know how to also enable it to only show the first character given an email character count varies. This is my attempt so far,

```
SELECT name, REPLACE(emailAddress,substr(emailAddress, instr(emailAddress, '@')-3,2),'***') emailMask

FROM  myEmailTable
```

I thought perhaps Oracle's REGEXP_REPLACE and REGEXP_INSTR might be more suitable. Or I thought maybe I could extract the first letter from the email column and then concatenate it.

Any advice would be really appreciated. I have inserted a table below to help illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

| name | emailAddress | emailMask |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bon Jovi | BonJovi@gmail.com | B*****i@gmail.com |
| Dan Brown | Dbrown@gmail.com | D****n@gmail.com |

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've come up with: Take the first character, pad it to the desired length with *, then add the rest.

```
select
  rpad(substr(emailaddress, 1, 1), instr(emailaddress, '@') - 2, '*') ||
  substr(emailaddress, instr(emailaddress, '@') - 1)
from mytable;
```

Comment: Oops, seems I was a little late. Littlefoot posted about the same answer twenty minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solution works! This is probably the most straight forward answer so I will mark this as the answer. Thanks again

Comment: True but yours is less complicated, if I can avoid a With statement for this I will :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, simple option works the best.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (emailaddress) as
  2    (select 'BonJovi@gmail.com'     from dual union all
  3     select 'Dbrown@gmail.com'      from dual union all
  4     select 'Little.Foot@yahoo.com' from dual
  5    ),
```

Query begins here: extract part of the email address that precedes the `@` sign, find its length (so that you'd know parameters for the `LPAD` function, and the last part (that follows the `@` sign).

```
  6  temp as
  7    (select emailaddress,
  8            substr(emailaddress, 1, instr(emailaddress, '@') - 1) first_part,
  9            length(substr(emailaddress, 1, instr(emailaddress, '@') - 1)) len,
 10            substr(emailaddress, instr(emailaddress, '@')) second_part
 11     from test
 12    )
```

Finally, concatenate the first letter to asterisks and the last letter, along with the whole second part of the email address:

```
 13  select emailaddress,
 14         substr(first_part, 1, 1) || lpad('*', len - 2, '*') || substr(first_part, -1)
 15           || second_part as result
 16  from temp;

EMAILADDRESS          RESULT
--------------------- ------------------------------
BonJovi@gmail.com     B*****i@gmail.com
Dbrown@gmail.com      D****n@gmail.com
Little.Foot@yahoo.com L*********t@yahoo.com

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace the characters before @. Your following SQL should look like this.

```
select name,
       emailAddress,
       regexp_replace(emailAddress, '(.).+', '\1') || lpad('*', length(regexp_replace(emailAddress, '.(.+).@.+', '\1')), '*') || regexp_replace(emailAddress, '.+(.)@(.+)', '\1@\2') emailMask
from myEmailTable
```

- `.` means any character.
- `.+` means any character (min. one or more).

Reference:

- [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html)

Comment: That's really nice, but - did you actually try it? I did, in 11g and 18c - the result is a single asterisk sign `*` which isn't exactly what the OP expects.

Comment: I did try this too and wondered if I needed to tweak it returned the same result for me. I still appreciate any one chipping in. Thanks for the reference I will take a look as I would like to understand how it works in case I need to tweak something in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just a little change in the REGEXP_REPLACE parameters from my side like so:

```
select column_value, regexp_replace(column_value, '(.).*?(.?@.*)', '\1***\2') rr 
from table(sys.odciVarchar2List('', 'a', 'abc', 'a@bc', 'ab@', 'ab@c', 'abcd@efgh'))
```

The fiddle of the above http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b32/6145

Comment: This is a nice solution for the missing `VALUES` expression in Oracle. But the OP wants one * for every character replaced, not a fixed length '***'.

Comment: Thank you  I see the fiddle working, That's a great site and I think it will be useful to me.